# How to give user access for parameters in Jenkins basused on user role in Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to give user access for parameters in Jenkins basused on user role.

so I am using Role-based Authorization Strategy and Active Choices parameter plugins and trying to do this and I successfully gave user access for parameters based on user name but not based on user roles.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.User

// Get the current user
User currentUser = User.current()

// Get the username of the current user
String currentUsername = currentUser != null ? currentUser.fullName : null

// Define the available environments based on usernames
def envChoices = []

if (currentUsername == "DevUser1") {
envChoices += "DEV"
}

if (currentUsername == "QAUser1") {
envChoices += "QA"
}

// Check if the user has the role "admin" to list all parameters (DEV, QA, PROD)
if (currentUsername == "Admin") {
envChoices += ["DEV", "QA", "PROD"]
}

return envChoices
```

I want to do the same based on user roles.

Also how to list user roles in Jenkins groovy script console does Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin have variables? I could not find it.